# Want to loop through the columns of dataframes in a list

Tags: r, loops

I would like to loop through a list of dataframes and change the column names (I want each of the columns to have the same name)
Does anyone have a solution using the following data?

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, z = 3:12)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, z = 3:12)
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, z = 3:12)

x <- list(df, df2, df3)
```

Either using a for loop or apply?  Would actually love to see both if possible

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: What do you mean by that? You want all the 3 columns to have identical name?

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(x)) colnames(x[[i]]) <- c("One", "Two", "Tree")`

Comment: no I want the column names of the dataframes in the list to have identical names. For excample, changing them from c(x,y,z) to c(a,b,c)

Comment: @Ben - that's what the suggested code does. Alternatively, `lapply(x, setNames, c("a","b","c"))`

Comment: Or `lapply(x, function(x) "names<-"(x, c("a","b","c")))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - which is all `setNames` does, so might as well use the simpler version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both hrbrmstr and David Arenburg's answers are perfect.